# How to predict enzyme activity computationally

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

if I have an enzyme and its corresponding substrate, are there computational methods that I can use to predict its enzymatic activities? I understand that we can determine its activity using various enzyme assays, but I'm not sure whether these activities can be reliably predicted with computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "its enzymatic activities"? Which of the things you understand can be measured experimentally are you asking about?

Comment: There are numerous studies using molecular dynamics to analyze enzymatic activity.